# Unable to access parent class properties

Tags: typescript

Please see the TypeScript code below:

```
class x {
  a = 20;
  f1(){
    console.log("parent > " + this.a);
  }
}
class y extends x {
  a = 10;
  f1(x?:number){
     console.log("chold > " + this.a);
    super.f1();
  }
}
let z = new y();
z.f1();
```

When I run the below compiled code in Chrome, I get child = 10 and parent = 10 .

What is the correct way of accessing parent class properties from parent class as `this` does not seem to work.

Comment: The code is working perfectly. You are just overriding the value of member `a`. There's no way to get to the value which was set in `x`.

Comment: So do i have to study the base class first and design my child class accordingly  ,  because if i specify a data member in my child class with the same name it might brake the base class functionality ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. But if you declare `a` to be private then the compiler will complain if you try to redeclare it

Answer (score 2):

> What is the correct way of accessing parent class properties from parent class as `this` does not seams to work.

`this` points to the current instance. `this.a` will point to the same value in the parent and the class. Essentially, `a` is overridden and when the parent accesses `this.a` it accesses the child property.

## More

- Parent methods are accessible via `super` even after overriding
- Parent properties are *overridden* permanently

## Docs

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/classes.html